# GitLab server: broken link from tree to blob

Tags: git, server, gitlab, fsck

Been getting a report from my GitLab **server** `repocheck.md` that there is a problem in one of my repositories.  This is the problem:

```
    E, [2020-04-04T10:25:00.323291 #27099] ERROR -- : Could not fsck repository: broken link from tree 8c7ba0f6c712df32e991ae9262f1c7514fd22473
    to blob 806164c98a18ddc2295c246e5509674471d6f54a
    missing blob 806164c98a18ddc2295c246e5509674471d6f54a
```

How can I resolve this problem on the server?

I have a good copy of that repo on a client:

```
Pete@sev MINGW64 ~/Documents/path/to/client/repo (master)
$ git gc
Enumerating objects: 536, done.
Counting objects: 100% (536/536), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (424/424), done.
Writing objects: 100% (536/536), done.
Total 536 (delta 177), reused 338 (delta 104)

Pete@sev MINGW64 ~/Documents/path/to/client/repo (master)
$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (536/536), done.
```

Comment: Force push the good copy to the server.

Comment: Thx.  Did not fix it.  Tried `git push --force` (no fix), then `git push --force-with-lease` (no fix).

Comment: Otherwise, try to identify from your local repo on which branch the missing object lies, then do `git push --no-thin branch-at-stake:branch-at-stake`.

Comment: (cf. the doc of [`git push --no-thin`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---no-thin))

Comment: Thx.  Nice suggestion about `--no-thin`!  Still did not fix the problem.  This looks similar to an unresolved problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428788/git-returns-failed-to-run-repack-and-inflate-returned-errors. Also tried running `git-repair` on the server directory but no fix.  Next, will copy the .git directory contents to my server (after making archive of existing server contents) and re-scan with `git fsck --full`.  Expecting glory with that.

Comment: ... and THAT fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since force push from the good local repo and `git-repair` on the server did not solve the problem, copied the contents of the `.git` directory from the good local repo to the server's file space (replacing all contents under the `repo.git/` directory).  Then ran `git fsck --full` to confirm the problem was gone.  And it was gone.

Comment: In our case, we had to create a bare repo from the local version. And then copied to server. It worked!!!!